# Проблемы с конфигурацией JNDI на Apache Tomcat 9.0.17

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc

Не получается правильно сконфигурурировать JNDI (все делаю в соответствии с документацией), однако, при старте возникает **вот такая ошибка**:

```
2019-03-20 08:36:20.744 WARN  - o.s.w.c.support.XmlWebApplicationContext -  Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/master] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
2019-03-20 08:36:20.773 ERROR - o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
 Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/master] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4682) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5150) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1729) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.17]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:457) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:406) [catalina.jar:9.0.17]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:289) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.17]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:361) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
**Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/master] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].**
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/master] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:817) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.17]
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:163) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.17]
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:155) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:179) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:106) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:231) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:217) ~[spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 69 common frames omitted
```

**Моя конфигурация для файла web.xml:**

```
    <resource-ref>
    <description>MySQL Datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/master</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

**Конфигурация в файле server.xml (path:/conf/server.xml):**

```
  <GlobalNamingResources>

<!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
     UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
-->
<Resource auth="Container" 
      description="User database that can be updated and saved" 
      factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory" 
      name="UserDatabase" 
      pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" 
      type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"/>
```

**Конфигурация для файла context.xml (path:/conf/context.xml):**

```
<Context>

<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/tomcat-web.xml</WatchedResource>
<WatchedResource>${catalina.base}/conf/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Resource name="jdbc/master" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
           username="root" password="routeplanner" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/routeplanner?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
```

Comment: Сам Tomcat работает. Database "routeplanner" также создана

Comment: Как выглядит имя JNDI в бине Spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел 2 ошибки:

1. Не подложил mysql-connector в ${CATALINA_HOME}/lib.
2. Неправильно задал имя БД, вот так должны выглядить конфигурационные файлы для БД routeplanner:

***conf/context.xml:***

`<Resource name="jdbc/routeplanner" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
               maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
               username="root" password="routeplanner" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/routeplanner"/>`

ФАЙЛ ***conf/server.xml*** оставляем в первоначальном виде

Файл ***web.xml***, который находится в приложении, выглядит следующим образом:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>MySQL Datasource</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/routeplanner</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```